# font.getsize() seems not to work with "\n" (new lines) inside the parameter

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

The used font: https://www.fontspace.com/abeezee-font-f30774

```
ImageFont.truetype(*path/to/font*, 300)
font.getsize("1\n\r0\n\r9")  # returns: (1080, 280) which is wrong!
image = np.full(shape=(1, 1, 3), fill_value=0, dtype=np.uint8)
image = Image.fromarray(image, mode="RGB")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.multiline_textsize(text="1\n\r0\n\r9", font=font, spacing=0)  # returns: (180, 837) which is correct"
```

Why are the results different? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So The main error was: 
1) for multiline text we should use:

```
 PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.multiline_text(xy, text, fill=None, font=None, anchor=None, spacing=0, align="left", direction=None, features=None, language=None)
```

In addition .getsize() returned a height that is a little too big. The height that worked for me was:

```
font.getmask(digit).size[1]
```

wich is the same to:

```
font.getsize(digit)[1] - font.getoffset(digit)[1]
```